# Reverse for '' with arguments '()' and keyword arguments '{}' not found. 0 pattern(s) tried: []

Tags: python, django

I am facing an error when I try to use the `login` function from `django.contrib.auth.views`. The error I get is `Reverse for '' with arguments '()' and keyword arguments '{}' not found. 0 pattern(s) tried: []`. There are similar questions on SO on the same topic but all relate to a function. Here, in the error message the error string does not mention any function which has me confused. 
Below are the settings.py and urls.py file. let me know if any other information is required.

urls.py

```
    from django.conf.urls import patterns, include, url
    from django.conf import settings
    from django.conf.urls.static import static
    from django.contrib.auth import views as auth_views

    from django.contrib import admin
    admin.autodiscover()

    from bootcamp.core import views as core_views
    from bootcamp.authentication import views as bootcamp_auth_views
    from bootcamp.activities import views as activities_views
    from bootcamp.search import views as search_views

    urlpatterns = [
        url(r'^$', core_views.home, name='home'),
        url(r'^login', auth_views.login, {'template_name': 'core/cover.html'}, name='login'),
        url(r'^logout', auth_views.logout, {'next_page': '/'}, name='logout'),
        url(r'^signup/$', bootcamp_auth_views.signup, name='signup'),
        url(r'^settings/$', core_views.settings, name='settings'),
        url(r'^settings/picture/$', core_views.picture, name='picture'),
        url(r'^settings/upload_picture/$', core_views.upload_picture, name='upload_picture'),
        url(r'^settings/save_uploaded_picture/$', core_views.save_uploaded_picture, name='save_uploaded_picture'),
        url(r'^settings/password/$', core_views.password, name='password'),
        url(r'^network/$', core_views.network, name='network'),
        url(r'^feeds/', include('bootcamp.feeds.urls')),
        url(r'^questions/', include('bootcamp.questions.urls')),
        url(r'^articles/', include('bootcamp.articles.urls')),
        url(r'^messages/', include('bootcamp.messenger.urls')),
        url(r'^notifications/$', activities_views.notifications, name='notifications'),
        url(r'^notifications/last/$', activities_views.last_notifications, name='last_notifications'),
        url(r'^notifications/check/$', activities_views.check_notifications, name='check_notifications'),
        url(r'^search/$', search_views.search, name='search'),
        url(r'^(?P<username>[^/]+)/$', core_views.profile, name='profile'),
        url(r'^i18n/', include('django.conf.urls.i18n', namespace='i18n')),
        url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
    ]
```

settings.py

```
INSTALLED_APPS = (
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'django.contrib.humanize',

    'bootcamp.activities',
    'bootcamp.articles',
    'bootcamp.authentication',
    'bootcamp.core',
    'bootcamp.feeds',
    'bootcamp.messenger',
    'bootcamp.questions',
    'bootcamp.search',
)

MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES = (
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.locale.LocaleMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [PROJECT_DIR.child('templates')],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'debug':DEBUG,
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]
```

**EDIT**

Adding the template core/cover.html

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}
{% load staticfiles %}
{% load i18n %}

{% block head %}
  <link href="{% static 'css/cover.css' %}" rel="stylesheet">
{% endblock head %}

{% block body %}
  <div class="cover">
    <h1 class="logo">muHUB</h1>
    {% if form.non_field_errors %}
      {% for error in form.non_field_errors %}
        <div class="alert alert-danger alert-dismissable">
          <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
          {{ error }}
        </div>
      {% endfor %}
    {% endif %}
    <div class="login">
      <h2>{% trans 'Log in' %}</h2>
      <form method="post" action="{% url 'login' %}" role="form">
        {% csrf_token %}
        <div class="form-group{% if form.username.errors %} has-error{% endif %}">
          <label for="username">{% trans 'Username' %}</label>
          <input type="text" class="form-control" id="username" name="username">
          {% for error in form.username.errors %}
            <label class="control-label">{{ error }}</label>
          {% endfor %}
        </div>
        <div class="form-group{% if form.password.errors %} has-error{% endif %}">
          <label for="password">{% trans 'Password' %}</label>
          <input type="password" class="form-control" id="password" name="password">
          {% for error in form.password.errors %}
            <label class="control-label">{{ error }}</label>
          {% endfor %}
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
          <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">{% trans 'Log in' %}</button>
          <a href="{% url 'signup' %}" class="btn btn-link">{% trans 'Sign up for muHUB' %}</a>
        </div>
      </form>
    </div>
  </div>
{% endblock body %}
```

**EDIT 2**

Adding the traceback

```
Traceback:

File "C:\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py" in get_response
  149.                     response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)

File "C:\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py" in get_response
  147.                     response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)

File "C:\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\auth\views.py" in inner
  49.         return func(*args, **kwargs)

File "C:\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\django\views\decorators\debug.py" in sensitive_post_parameters_wrapper
  76.             return view(request, *args, **kwargs)

File "C:\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\django\utils\decorators.py" in _wrapped_view
  149.                     response = view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)

File "C:\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\django\views\decorators\cache.py" in _wrapped_view_func
  57.         response = view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)

File "C:\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\auth\views.py" in login
  73.                 redirect_to = resolve_url(settings.LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL)

File "C:\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\django\shortcuts.py" in resolve_url
  204.         return urlresolvers.reverse(to, args=args, kwargs=kwargs)

File "C:\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\django\core\urlresolvers.py" in reverse
  600.     return force_text(iri_to_uri(resolver._reverse_with_prefix(view, prefix, *args, **kwargs)))

File "C:\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\django\core\urlresolvers.py" in _reverse_with_prefix
  508.                              (lookup_view_s, args, kwargs, len(patterns), patterns))

Exception Type: NoReverseMatch at /login/
Exception Value: Reverse for '' with arguments '()' and keyword arguments '{}' not found. 0 pattern(s) tried: []
```

Comment: what's the template or view where you are doing the reverse

Comment: @e4c5: Please check the edit. I have added the template.

Comment: I don't think this the code that produces the error. There must be a full stack trace, please post it.

Comment: @e4c5: I have pasted the traceback in edit 2. The traceback doesn't mention any file that I have created. It refers to the files in the site-packages.

Comment: Please update the settings.py section to include LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL and related.

Comment: that works. thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is in your LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL, this the only code in the stacktrace that has a connection to your own code.

```
File "C:\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\auth\views.py" in login
  73.                 redirect_to = resolve_url(settings.LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL)
```

I suspect that your login redirect url is constructed with the help of reverse or it's improperly set.